# Scoping is different in $.ajax.done() vs $.ajax.fail()?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm having a hard time with something that seems very simple. I can access the variable 'newUser' which sits outside the $.ajax call from .done() but not from .fail(). Why would the scoping be different?

```js
let newUser = new User({
    id: -1,
    username: self.newUserUsername(),
    firstName: self.newUserFirstName(),
    lastName: self.newUserLastName(),
    email: self.newUserEmail(),
    password: self.newUserPassword(),
    is_active: true
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: Util.addCsrfHeader,
    url: "/api/users/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ko.toJSON(newUser)
})
.done(function(data) {
    // newUser is successfully found and used
    newUser.id(data.id);
    self.users.push(newUser);
})
.fail(function(data) {
    // reference error: newUser is not defined
    alert(newUser);
});
```

As you might imagine I trigger .done() with a successful call to the (Django) backend and .fail() with a call that I know will make the backend return a status 400 (duplicate value).

Comment: This code doesn't include jQuery, nor a definition for user, Utils, self, or knockout. When modified, the problem described is not reproducible.

Comment: Any chance you have another `newUser` variable somewhere else in the code?

Comment: No sir. I was hoping I was missing something obvious but that doesnt seem to be the case given the first answer lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see the assertion is incorrect in the question. The fail method does have the proper scope.

```js
let newUser = {
    id: -1,
    username: "self.newUserUsername()",
    firstName: "self.newUserFirstName()",
    lastName: "self.newUserLastName()",
    email: "self.newUserEmail()",
    password: "self.newUserPassword()",
    is_active: true
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    /*beforeSend: Util.addCsrfHeader,*/ //no need to induce fail state
    url: "/api/users/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "ko.toJSON(newUser)" //mocked for snippet purposes
})
.done(function(data) {
    // newUser is successfully found and used
    console.log("done", newUser); //never happens in snippets though
})
.fail(function(data) {
    // ---reference error: newUser is not defined---
    // newUser is fine.
    console.log("fail", newUser);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: However, a statement that the assertion in the question is wrong is not really an answer. He's presumably having a problem in his real code, and didn't express it properly in the question. We need to get more information before we can answer properly.

Comment: I made the edits suggested. This is not an answer though @Barmar, it is a community wiki showing an example of the problem not being reproducible. Would you have preferred a comment with a jsfiddle link? As a wiki, please feel free in the future to make any changes you see fit, as they are supposed to be more community driven than anything else. Yes, with more clarification the question could *potentially* become answerable, but in its current state it is not, and very often the current state is as far as OP's tend to go. Many fruitless efforts have been made to improve attentiveness.